# HTML <pre> tag causes linebreaks

Tags: html, css, newline, line-breaks, pre

I'm using CSS (via JQuery , but not relevant to this question) to highlight certain elements within an HTML file: I'm using "pre" tags to separate out logical elements in my file, but I noticed that "pre" tags seem to leave newlines between elements.

Can I get rid of these using CSS ?

(Or what shall I use instead of "pre" tags? The text elements may contain HTML elements themeselves : which should *not* be rendered, and should be shown literally as source-code: hence my initial choice with "pre" tags)

Here's an example of the HTML I'm using: (Requires http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery for this example)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="error">
This is an error line.
    stack.trace.blah.blah
    more.blah.blah
    yadda.yadda.blah</pre>
<pre class="ok">
this is not an error line.it contains html
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;hello&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</pre>
<pre class="error">
This is an error line.
    stack.trace.blah.blah
    more.blah.blah
    yadda.yadda.blah</pre>
<pre class="ok">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("pre.error").css({"background-color":"red","color":"white","display":"block","padding":"0", "margin":"0"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Firefox 3.6.12.
This is what the code above results in:
[image]

And this is simulated output of what I want (switched to yellow, only because I used my vim editor to this, pretend it's red!)

[image]

SOLUTION:

Is to use 'display:inline' for all PRE tags. (Previously I was only applying the 'display:inline' to the 'error' tags in the example above, and had forget to do the same for 'ok' pre tags.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve now. You want to have linebreaks without having linebreaks? Perhaps it would help to simulate your expected output.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sotiris' suggestion to set the margin and padding definitely ought to work in that case, so I would suspect there is something overriding the margin/padding - perhaps a line height somewhere, or even a more specific margin somewhere else in your CSS. Do you have Firebug installed? It will let you highlight the pre tags and investigate whether there is a rogue margin screwing with your layout.

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for here, but find it fascinating that everyone answering seems to have answered a completely different question to all the other answers. Answers involve block level vs inline elements, entity escaping, CSS white space handling, removing margins and padding - they are all different answers to different questions. Just an observation really.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's because `<pre>` has a default style `display: block`, use in your css `pre { display: inline}`

as for your edit, you need to add `margin: 0;` to ALL the pre blocks, not just the ones you want to style:

```
pre {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You should try to avoid styling with JS whenever possible, but if you really must:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("pre.error").css({"background-color":"red","color":"white","display":"block","padding":"0", "margin":"0"});
    $("pre").css({ "margin" : 0, "padding" : 0 })
</script>
```

Comment: aye - not supported "out of the box" in IE < 7 tho iirc - set hasLayout first and then `display: inline;` for it to work there.

Comment: @monojohnny, explain further? :)

Comment: Yes: that works for my Firefox - I had to include an extra newline at the end of each of the contents of the "pre".

Comment: @Marko - I mean instead of <pre>hello there</pre> I now need to add in a trailing newline like <pre>hello there [newline]</pre> to ensure the next <pre> element doesn't continue where the other one finished. Make sense?

Comment: Actually I appear to be wrong here : this doesn't appear to work for me. It might be something I have done, but have to uncheck the answer for now whilst I do this...

Comment: Sorry Marko - your solution didn't seem to work (I have re-edited my initial post to include a screenshot and better illustrated code) - perhaps I have made a mistake here...

Comment: Ok - this _does_ work - thanks to everybody - it was because I have a mixture of pre tags - and was only introducing the display:inline for the 'error' pre elements and not the 'ok' pre elements. All works now. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The pre tag is a block level element, so it will behave like any other block level element and stack vertically (like paragraph, div, etc). You can set it to display:inline instead, I guess.

But better would be to use the `<code>` tag, which is inline by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: <code> + &gt; and &lt; wins this one. Looks right and is semantically correct.

Comment: Actually the 'code' tag seems to be trickier to use: its stripping out leading spaces whereas pre is (correctly for my case) keeping them.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the pre tag to be a inline element by adding this in head:

```
<style type='text/css'> pre {display: inline;} </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can fix with css as follow

```
pre {
    width: 600px;                          /* specify width  */
    white-space: pre-wrap;                 /* CSS3 browsers  */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* 1999+ Mozilla  */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;                /* Opera 4 thru 6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;              /* Opera 7 and up */
    word-wrap: break-word;                 /* IE 5.5+ and up */

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer so people can understand what you did to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using jQuery for something that can be achieved via CSS?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    pre {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    pre.error {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <pre class="error">
This is an error line.
    stack.trace.blah.blah
    more.blah.blah
    yadda.yadda.blah</pre>
    <pre class="ok">
this is not an error line.it contains html
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;hello&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</pre>
    <pre class="error">
This is an error line.
    stack.trace.blah.blah
    more.blah.blah
    yadda.yadda.blah</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have other reasons for wanting to use JQuery (mainly so that I can [more easily] apply styling dynamically) - using JQuery (I would say) shouldn't be an important difference for this issue - since (in essence) JQuery is using just using Javascript to apply CSS rules..(I thought...)

Comment: @monojohnny: Which bits are going to be dynamic? Are you really likely to want to change the `padding` or `margin` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HTML source to use special chars instead of `< >` (like `&lt; &gt;`). You can do this with notepad++ using TextFX Plugin (Encode HTML) or in eclipse you can do this with anyedit tools.

Comment: use special chars instead of < > (like & lt;  &gt; ).

Comment: you can change display properties of pre but it is not what pre for. pre is for preformatted text.

Comment: The pre is doing the correct job for what I need - the trouble is , it introduces a full newline _between_ each pre; it is this extra line I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

```
pre { margin: 0; }
```

[should give you the rendering in the second picture](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Cstyle%3E%0D%0Apre%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20margin%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Apre.error%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20background%3A%20red%3B%0D%0A%20%20color%3A%20white%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0D%0A%3Cpre%20class%3D%22error%22%3E%0D%0AThis%20is%20an%20error%20line.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stack.trace.blah.blah%0D%0A%20%20%20%20more.blah.blah%0D%0A%20%20%20%20yadda.yadda.blah%3C%2Fpre%3E%0D%0A%3Cpre%20class%3D%22ok%22%3E%0D%0Athis%20is%20not%20an%20error%20line.it%20contains%20html%0D%0A%26lt%3Bhtml%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bhead%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fhead%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bbody%26gt%3Bhello%26lt%3B%2Fbody%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fhtml%26gt%3B%3C%2Fpre%3E%0D%0A%3Cpre%20class%3D%22error%22%3E%0D%0AThis%20is%20an%20error%20line.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stack.trace.blah.blah%0D%0A%20%20%20%20more.blah.blah%0D%0A%20%20%20%20yadda.yadda.blah%3C%2Fpre%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A). Your snippet probably doesn't work because you don't remove the default margin from the `pre.ok`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `padding:0` and `margin:0` for `pre` in css

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Tried this (edited my original post) - but still not doing what I need. I have added a screenshot to show what I mean , and also what I want as the end-result.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pre, instead escape the characters you want to display literally. Like `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>`. 
When you render your page, you can use a function like `htmlentities()` (PHP) to escape these characters for you.

Comment: So do you mean: Use 'div' or 'p' or 'span' (which would you recommend actually?) , pre-process the in-line text (to 'literalize' any HTML in there) and use CSS to make it look like what I want?