# PRE and white-spaces behavior

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a txt file in the browser while maintining it's format and layout. Now i have accomplished this with sucess using both the pre tag and white-spaces.

My problem with the pre tag is the space it adds before and after the line (i don't need that).

white-spaces works perfectly, but sometimes there will be a random line (or lines) wich will truncate.

I'm testing this only on IE (since it's for an intranet and folks here won't touch another browser).

When i see the source code on IE the lines wich are truncated have the correct white-spaces tag, but it does not display correctly on the browser.

```
<p style="white-space: pre;display: inline;">    Any    kind of   text      here </p>
```

Is this the browser's fault or my mistake? 
Is there a better way to do this? 
Is there a way to remove the spaces before and after the line from the pre tag?

Thank you all

Comment: "My problem with the pre tag is the space it adds before and after the line (i don't need that)" - what space do you mean?

Comment: Well at least on IE10, it seems like there is a BR tag before and after each line.

Comment: I think you're better off applying regex in JS. Unless you can change the content of the txt files which is where the spaces are coming from

Comment: Actually is a space between lines.

Comment: The question is obscure. E.g., the title mentions PRE, but the code sample shown has no such element. A question should specify code and observed facts rather than speculation of causes.

Comment: Jukka, i have used both ways i.e. the same line above with only just pre and the example i have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Pre tag doesn't add space before and after a line, other than the space in the text there (4 spaces before Any, 1 space after here).

There may be another tag that is creating margin. `<body>` by default, has 8px margins.

Also tried placing two `<p>` back to back, and no newlines separated the tags.

Testing the following in a html file:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; font-family: 'Courier New',Courier, monospace"><p style="white-space: pre;display: inline; margin: 0px;">    Any    kind of   text      here </p><p style="white-space: pre;display: inline; ">    Any    kind of   text      here </p></body>
```

Comment: The space i refered to is between lines.  Also, could this be the problem?    body{
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size: 9pt;
}

Comment: I added that. It didn't put the <p> on separate lines. You'll need to use a webpage inspection tool like in Chrome or Firefox. It'll show you what styles are applied to what elements. But you said it only happens in IE10?

Comment: @CuervoJones Otherwise, you're stuck doing what I'm doing, progressively adding more of the CSS to the page until you see the "bug".

Answer (score 0):

In the end i followed the suggestions here:
[HTML <pre> tag causes linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233869/html-pre-tag-causes-linebreaks)

Worked without a flaw.