# How to remove the blank lines before and after html pre-formatted text?

Tags: html, pre

I want to insert pre-formatted text into html text, but the renderer insists on adding blank lines before and after the pre-formatted text. For example, this html code:

> <html>
> <body>
> Before text
> <pre>
> Line 1: Pre-formatted text
> Line 2: Pre-formatted text
> </pre>
> After text
> </body>
> </html>

results in this output:

> Before text
>
> ```
> Line 1: Pre-formatted text
> Line 2: Pre-formatted text
> ```
>
> After text

Is there any way of getting rid of the leading and trailing blank lines? If I'd wanted them, I could have put them in myself!

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233869/html-pre-tag-causes-linebreaks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML <pre> tag causes linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233869/html-pre-tag-causes-linebreaks)

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for those links! I found a working solution there -- see my answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer! Sorry for the duplicate comments. I didn't realize flagging a duplicate added a comment automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many suggestions in the possible duplicates posted in the comments. The solution that works for me is to replace `<pre>` with `<pre style="margin:0">`, and to add `<br>` outside the pre-formatted text to compensate as required.